# Calcular valores (R$) a partir da quantidade

Tags: php

Não sei se o título explica bem a dúvida, mas eu vou dar um exemplo:

Um produto custa 50 centavos cada. Quero que os clientes selecionem o número de produtos que eles desejam levar. Até ai, tudo bem.

Se eu multiplicar R$0,50xNumeroPar, o resultado é um inteiro.

Porém, se eu multiplicar por um numero ímpar, o resultado é um número quebrado.

Meu código:

```
 if($mc_quantia == 1) {
     //Se a quantia for 1, o preço será 50 centavos                   
     $item = "R$0,50";
 } else {
     //Se não, pegue a quantia e divida por 2 (Porque cada 50 centavos é meio real, então eu preciso dividir por 2)
     $id_4 = $mc_quantia/2;

     $item = 'R$'.$id_4.',00';
 }
```

O problema:

Se a quantia for 3, vai retornar R$1.50,00

Eu gostaria que retornasse direto o R$1,50

Podem me ajudar??

Comment: Está misturando formatação string com números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez você não conheça ainda, mas para este estes cálculos existe um tipo de variável chamado `float`, que lhe permite trabalhar com números fracionados, sem precisar fazer essa lógica com o inteiro.

Tente isto:

```
 if($mc_quantia == 1) {
     $item = "R$0,50";
 } else {
     $id_4 = $mc_quantia*0.5;
     $item = 'R$'.number_format($id_4, 2, ',', '.');
 }
```

este código acima resolveria o seu problema, abaixo segue o ideal, visto que o resultado é o mesmo:

```
//O if/else é totalmente desnecessário, visto que mesmo sendo a quantidade 1,
//irá retornar o valor calculado corretamente
$id_4 = $mc_quantia*0.5;
$item = 'R$'.number_format($id_4, 2, ',', '.');
```

**OBS. Segundo documentação [oficial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), essa função aceita apenas 1, 2 ou 4 parâmetros, não 3**

Comment: Que versão do php está usando? Testei e não funcionou, deu erro `Wrong parameter count for number_format()`. Tive que colocar assim: `$item = 'R$'.number_format($id_4, 2, ',', '');`

Comment: Estranho, pois independente da versão somente o primeiro parâmetro é obrigatório.

Comment: Poderia dizer qual a versão?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta...

Comment: Já conhecia a double e a float, mas não sabia qual era a diferença ou então para o que servia cada uma. De qualquer forma, valeu.

Comment: Agora sim. Vou dar upvote.

Comment: o ultimo argumento pode ser qualquer string, ela só precisa ser passada como parâmetro, como editei na resposta, havia colocado errado, pois 3 parâmetros não são possíveis

Comment: Claro, conforme o que escrevi antes ;)

Comment: E sobre o Else e o If, eu sei que nem era necessário, mas como eu não conhecia o negocio do float, eu fiz essa gambiarra ali pra retornar certinho.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplificar um pouco mais o código:

```
$valor_unidade = 0.50;

$item = "R$" . number_format($valor_unidade * $mc_quantia);
```

E como na documentação do number_format, você pode formatar a variavel como gostaria:

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// Notação Inglesa (padrão)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,234

// Notação Francesa
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// Notação Inglesa com separador de milhar
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```